# How to inspect a variable when testing with `drush test-run`.

Tags: debugging, testing, drush

When testing with my SimpleTests, I want to inspect a variable. `var_dump()` and the likes are not being rendered in the output of Drush, Xdebug interactive debugger does not work due to the simulated browser being ran in `DrupalWebTest`.

How can I render, export, inspect or otherwise dump the contents of a variable in my code? I.e. the `DrupalWebTest` of `dpm()`, `var_export()` and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [Troubleshooting Tests](https://drupal.org/node/394976) has a number of insights:

1. Use [`debug()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/debug/7) in Drupal 7. This will work during testing, and display the output right in your test results.
2. Print them with a test that always passes (using something like `$this->pass(var_export($var, TRUE));`). It's a bit of a kludge, but it'll work in the absence of anything else.

Comment: debug() does nothing for me. Had to assert(TRUE

Comment: $this->pass() is functionally equivalent. Curious as to why this was downvoted.

Comment: It doesn't work at all in my experience.

Comment: `assertTrue(FALSE, $msg);` will always be your friend though.

Answer (score 2):

Call [DrupalTestCase::assert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalTestCase%3a%3aassert/7) passing the message to show.

```
$this->assert(TRUE,
  t('Variable content: @variable', array('@variable' => var_export($variable, TRUE))
);
```

This is similar to the code used by [DrupalTestCase::assertIdentical()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalTestCase%3a%3aassertIdentical/7). The difference is that in your case the first argument is `TRUE` because you are just outputting the content of a variable, which never fails.

```
protected function assertIdentical($first, $second, $message = '', $group = 'Other') {
  return $this->assert($first === $second, $message ? $message : t('Value @first is identical to value @second.', array('@first' => var_export($first, TRUE), '@second' => var_export($second, TRUE))), $group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `print_r($variable)`?
For a human friendly output you could try

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($variable);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: obviously. But as stated, that output will be sent to the simulated browser and is not available on the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 solutions

1) you can use [watchdog](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7).

`watchdog($type, $message);`
Just put your variables with custom type name like:

```
watchdog('drush_test_run', print_r($message));
```

2) you can create some file `log.txt` and write variables into it with php file functions.

Comment: Watchdog won't work, because the database is wipte between all runs. Most test-suites will maintain the state (like the Database) after running tests; and only wipe everything clean just *before* running a test; not Drupal. The textfile would work, but in that case PHPs logs are a far better option.

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Any of these answers would be OK under most circumstances except that the problem I was having with a specific test case was do to the fact that I implemented an `exec` call and that function captures all output.

In my case I replaced the `exec` call with [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) and that fixed the issue for me.